# Laravel - GroupBy with condition

Tags: mysql, laravel, group-by

I have a bunch of ToDo items, some of which are recurring. The same task may have a due_date every week/month/quarter etc. I'm tracking recurring ToDo items with a `recurring_identifier_id`. E.g. the January and February version of a ToDo task of would have the same `recurring_identifier_id` to link them.

I want to query the database to get all of the **unique** (recurring_identifier_id) **with the due_date most in the future**.

```
$collection = TodoItems::select('*')
    ->having('user_id', '=', $userId)
    ->groupBy('recurring_identifier_id')
    ->get();
```

The above query gets unique ToDo items with `groupBy('recurring_identifier_id')`. How can I make sure that for e.g. 10 ToDo items with the same `recurring_identifier_id`, that I grab the one with the due_date most in the future?

I haven't done a where clause to get ToDo items with a due_date between certain dates (e.g. start and end of month) as ToDo items could be monthly, quarterly, etc.